# Group by Nested List Identifier

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object as follows:

```
class ObjectParent
{
    public List<ObjectChild> ChildNumbers{ get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

class ObjectChild
{    
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<ObjectParent>` obj that I need to group by `ChildId` which is inside `ObjectChild`

How can I do so?

this is what i tried

```
    var groupedItemDetails = itemDetails
        .GroupBy(u => u.ChildNumbers.ChildId)
        .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Group and do what? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I want to loop throug each GroupItem which has list of 
 {ParentId, Property, ChildId}

Comment: Still not clear can you show some sample input and output you are expecting?

Comment: `ChildNumbers.GroupBy(g => g.ChildId)`

Comment: @ataravati but i need ParentId  as well so need to start by List<ObjectParent> obj.GroupBy(....

Comment: Then, explain what you need to do. And, show what you've done so far.

Comment: @JustinHomes - Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx) to flatten the list and then group by ChildId like this:-

```
var result = parents.SelectMany(x => x.ChildNumbers, (parentObj, childnum) => 
                                                 new { 
                                                         parentObj, childnum 
                                                     })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.childnum.ChildId)
                    .Select(x => new
                              {
                                 ChildId = x.Key,
                                 Properties = x.Select(z => z.childnum.Property),
                                 ParentIds = x.Select(z => z.parentObj.ParentId)
                              });
```

Check this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KnncZx) I have created with some sample data.